# Module Login on article Joomla 2.5

Tags: authentication, joomla, module

I created an article on joomla and I'd like to display a part for all(public) and another part of article only for registered users. Now I create a module that I integrated on article page, but I'd like to display the login. 
Alternatively I can create 2 page: a login page that redirect to the my registered article. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the login module, what you can do is, define a custom position for it by typing one in, rather than selecting one of the predefined ones, then embed it by using the following code:

```
{loadposition xxx}   //xxx being the position you defined
```

Or, you can use an extensions from the [Content Restriction](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction) category on JED to restrict content.

Personally, I think [Hider](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction/6004) might be your best choice, as it allows you to defines specific groups and specific content.

---

Alternatively, you can do it this way. Firstly, download and install [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) which allows you to use any code in your articles. Then use the following code inside your article and be sure to use the `{source}` tags:

```
{source}
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    if ($user->guest) {
        echo "some content";
        echo "Login to read more";
        echo "{loadposition xxx}";
    }
    else {
        echo "all content";
    }
{/source}
```

Comment: yes, i tried it, I use DirectPHP. But the echo "{loadposition xxx}"; don't display my module ( I set my own "position" on module)

Comment: @Edoz - Ah sorry. I have updated my answer with the exact extension I use on my own site so do this. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the built in show unauthorized feature that shows the intro but not the body to users who do not have authorization to see the article. YOu can  set this globally or article by article or with a menu link.